# django model form RegexValidator error message not showing up

Tags: django, forms, error-handling, model

I'm using the class below in the models.py to restrict file uploads to certain file extensions.

```
class ExtensionValidator(RegexValidator):
    def __init__(self, extensions, message=None):
        if not hasattr(extensions, '__iter__'):
            extensions = [extensions]
        regex = '\.(%s)$' % '|'.join(extensions)
        if message is None:
            message = 'File type not supported. Accepted types are: %s.' % ', '.join(extensions)
        super(ExtensionValidator, self).__init__(regex, message)

    def __call__(self, value):
        super(ExtensionValidator, self).__call__(value.name)
```

Here is the model form where it is called:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=product_types, default='choose')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images', blank=True, null=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product_file = models.FileField(upload_to='product_files', validators=[ExtensionValidator(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'zip'])], blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', kwargs={})
```

I've tested and the functionality works, but the error message is not showing up when the user submits the form.  For all forms I'm using an include - form.html below:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden_field }}
{% endfor %}

{% if form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.label_tag }}

    {% if form.is_bound %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm guessing I need to add something to the form.html to display the error message, just not sure what or where, yet.  I'm still researching this, but any guidance would be gratefully received.

**EDIT**:

As requested, here's the form class:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'product_type', 'price', 'image', 'image_url', 'product_file']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'url': 'Product URL',
            'product_type': 'Product Type',
            'description': 'Product Description',
            'image': 'Product Image',
            'image_url': 'Product Image URL',
            'price': 'Product Price',
            'product_file': 'Product File',
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}),
        }
```

**EDIT 2**:

...and here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="product card card-default">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title mb-4">Add Product</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post_url/" method="post" >
          {% csrf_token %}
                {% include 'includes/form.html' with form=form %}
          <input class="btn btn-product" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us your form class.

Comment: Thanks - edited the post and added the form class.

Comment: And can you also show how you are rendering the form tag itself?

Comment: Done - edited the original post again.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here, but is there a reason you are implementing your own file extension validator instead of using the [built-in one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator)?

Comment: No reason other than not knowing any other way.  I'm new and learning ...just can't make out why that error isn't showing.

Comment: One thing that the built in validator does that you don't is convert the extension to lower case before checking it. Other than that, I can't see where the issue could be - hopefully someone else will be able to.

Comment: Do errors on other fields show?

Comment: Yeah - if there's a required field it catches it.

Comment: But if the input has the required attribute it's catched by the browser, not django. If it helps, I would try to add a validation to another field, and see if it shows the error.

Comment: It's worth a shot...

Comment: When you click on the button, does it just reload the page, by losing all the filled out form fields? if so, most likely you are not handling the post properly in the view. Also, ExtensionValidator is an overkill, you can just have a modelform, and validate the extension types in the clean_ method

Comment: When you click on the button it takes you to the product page.  If the user tried to upload a file that is not allowed, there is no new product.  Likewise, if they have uploaded allowed files, there is a new product.  Thanks for the hint - I'll take a look at clean_method.

Comment: I decided to remove the custom validator extension and used this instead: `def clean_image(self):
        image_file = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not image_file.name.endswith(".jpg", "jpeg", "png"):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Only JPG, JPEG and PNG images accepted")
        return image_file` - again, functionality works, but no error message if I try to upload the wrong format.

Comment: I took advise and moved away from using this custom class, to the built in validator - thanks to all that offered help.